# overloaded += operator with multiple terms

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a two classes, a molecule and a single_atom class with overloaded operators +=, +, and *. + works as long as the two operands are a molecule or atom. * works with an atom or molecule and an int, and can be reversed.  += only works when the operand is a single molecule or atom but should be able to evauluate complex expressions.  How do I incorporate += so that the following works:

```
single_atom a1("sulpher");
single_atom a2("mercury");
Molecule m1(a1);
m1 += 3 * a1 + a2 * 4;
```

or even just:

```
m1 += 3 * a1;
```

Comment: Try parentheses. `m1 += ( 3 * a1 );`

Comment: @Yunnosch That will change nothing

Answer (score 0):

The whole right-hand side would need to allow temporaries properly, for example

```
3 * a1
```

would require

```
single_atom single_atom::operator*(int value) const;
```

Then that will return a `single_atom&&` that you can pass into the next operation. This will continue until finally you have an overload for `+=` that looks like

```
single_atom& single_atom::operator+=(single_atom&& rhs)
```

Comment: It will probably simplify things to have them as free operators, especially in the `3 * a1` case.